# Android: Printing via bluetooth or wifi

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, wifi

I have develop android application for phone and tablets that demands printing files (mostly print bill receipts ) to a Bluetooth printer.

For this task We would need a portable printer (handheld, it is important) that can connect to android phone via bluetooth or WiFi.

Is there any API or SDK available for connecting Android Device to Printer ?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a generic solution as far as I have found.  Each vendor has its own set of driver libraries.  For example, I have had a lot of luck with this particular printer:

http://www.citizen-systems.com/Product.aspx?id=123#1